# Unity Input System binding erase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
while (action.bindings.Any())
{
    action.ChangeBinding(0).Erase();
}
```

If I Erase all the bindings in action,
Unity warns

"**InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities.ReadOnlyArray`1[TValue].get_Item**"

How can I remove all the bindings in action?
If has the other way Let me know!

Comment: Typically can't modify an enumeration whilst iterating over it. `get_Item` is aware that something was removed thus making the iterator invalid. I don't know this specific API, but I'd imagine there is a `.Clear()` or similar.

Comment: If the `Erase` is somehow delayed then you might have an issue anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I guess you could just create a new action without any bindings

```
// Basically creating a clone but skipping the bindings parameter
var newAction = new InputAction(action.name, action.type, interactions = action.interactions, processors = action.processors,  expectedControlType = action.expectedControlType);

// Disable the current action so it isn't reacting to input anymore 
action.Disable();
action.Dispose();

// Enable the new action since a new InputAction starts disabled
newAction.Enable();

// Finally replace your field/variable
action = newAction;
```